# Clear Clipboard on KDE

Tags: c++, gtk, clipboard, fedora, kde-plasma

I am using gtk to clear the clipboard on Linux platforms with X11, and I was hoping that it would work across all Linux platforms. However, my gtk code does not work for Fedora KDE and some distributions of Fedora. When `clipboard_clear` function is called, the clipboard does not get cleared.

```
void clipboard_clear() {
  gtk_init(&args,NULL);
  GtkClipboard* cb = gtk_clipboard_get(GDK_SELECTION_PRIMARY);
  gtk_clipboard_clear(cb);
  gtk_clipboard_set_text(cb, "", 0);

  cb = gtk_clipboard_get(GDK_SELECTION_CLIPBOARD);
  gtk_clipboard_clear(cb);
  gtk_clipboard_set_text(cb, "", 0);
}
```

Is there anything that I can do to make this gtk implementation work as it suppose to on a Fedora KDE? If not, are there any libraries that can clear the clipboard on KDE and be statically linked? (Qt is not one among them because of licensing restrictions.)

Comment: What licensing restriction?

Comment: @LaszloPapp You cannot link statically to Qt unless you have a commercial licence.

Comment: Why would you link statically against a stable API, especially when already shipped on the KDE system as dynamic anyway?

Comment: Can you use gtk_clipboard_set_with_data() with a clear function to clear the clipboard?

Comment: Yes, I can. I will get back to you with the results.

Comment: @swtdrgn: any results?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I still haven't try the function that you suggested, but I rollbacked to the implementation with Qt. The clipboard cannot be cleared using Qt on Fedora KDE and Fedora LXDE (but it works on Linux Mint, Ubuntu, and Fedora Gnome/XFCE). The GTK code above works for Linux Mint, Ubuntu, and Fedora Gnome/XFCE, but it also does not work for Fedora KDE and Fedora LXDE.

Comment: The Qt implementation only clears the clipboard in its own process. It does not prevent the user from pasting the content on another process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External clipboard managers prevent the above code from clearing the clipboard.

On Fedora 19 KDE, `klipper` came pre-installed. After closing it, there wasn't any more problems with clearing the function. Similarly on Fedora 19 LXDE, `clipit` came pre-installed.

Comment: If I want a program to clear the clipboard(s) and keep them clear, do I need to implement a different solution for each Linux distro?